# Intent to call Shazam to recognize a song

Tags: android

Is there an intent to launch the application Shazam, then recognize a song and use the results in your own application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no officially published and supported URL: http://pastie.org/1656688/wrap has a list of some on the Activity classes implemented by Shazam. You might be able to launch one of them with `startActivityForResult` and read the return value.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use this shazam unofficial API which returns all the data you require. You can get the API from [here](https://rapidapi.com/yashmakan261/api/shazam8/)

PS: I created this API so you can contact me for any query